# Installing QGIS 3.22 on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, installation

I'm trying to install QGIS 3.22 on a MacOS Big Sur from this page :  https://download.qgis.org/qgisdata/QGIS-Website/live/html/en/site/forusers/download.html#

I download the Long-Term release "QGIS MacOS installer Version 3.22" but when I install it, it's QGIS 3.28 and not 3.22 that get installed.

I need this version to use the QSWAT+ plugin that only works with QGIS3.22 / Python 3.8 on MacOS.

I don't understand why 3.28 is installed instead of 3.22. How do I install this version?

Comment: You can get  it here: https://download.qgis.org/downloads/macos/ltr/qgis_ltr_final-3_22_16_20230203_132603.dmg. Here is list of macOS LTR versions: https://download.qgis.org/downloads/macos/ltr/?C=M;O=D